# lubuntu how to execute 2 commands in .desktop file?

Tags: scripts, .desktop

I have created a .desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` which runs the command

```
Exec= disper -d LVDS,VGA-0 -r auto -e -t right
```

Now I want to add a second command to run after the first command. How do I do this ?

Comment: Create a bash script, run multiple commands in it and run the bash script from your `.desktop`?

Answer (score 21):

Apart from calling an external bash script there is this option:

```
Exec=sh -c "disper -d LVDS,VGA-0 -r auto -e -t right; echo Running other command; echo ...and an other one"
```

Comment: I am using this variation to remedy some `conky` issues:   `Exec=sh -c "gnome-terminal & killall -SIGUSR1 conky"`

Comment: can any of the commands set an environment variable such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to wrap it all up in a script. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

disper -d LVDS,VGA-0 -r auto -e -t right
second_command_here
```

Save it somewhere, such as `~/bin/my_wrapper_script.sh`, and make it executable. Then change the `Exec` line of your `.desktop` file to point to it:

```
Exec=/home/my_username/my_wrapper_script.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html):

> The `Exec` key must contain a command line. A command line consists of an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments.

My understanding of the above being that the `Exec` key supports a single command and that command can only contain 1 executable followed by arguments for the executable.

My tests to combine commands:

```
firefox && gedit
firefox & gedit
firefox ; gedit
```

resulted in the second executable being read as an argument which seems to confirm the text.