# Jupyter Note book and Desktop Short cut

Tags: scripts, .desktop

I have the following problem. I have a .ipynb in a specific folder called ~/mho of course that I have to divulge I have an anaconda installation. My questions is how can I start up Jupyter from a desktop short cut, because I already have pycharm starting from a desktop short cut. I have the following .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/mho;conda init bash;conda activate;conda activate DataBaseOperations;jupyter notebook
```

I run the shell from the folder it is in it produces an error but runs.

```
~/Scriptfiles: sh mho.sh
```

But when I do the following and make it a desktop shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=sh /home/josemserrajr/Scriptfiles/mho.sh
Name=MhoNotebook
GenericName=Mho
Comment=Jupyter notebook
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Appplication;Network;
```

It doesn't run.

Can anybody point me in the right direction is what I want not possible? I have been basing off my research off these three questions: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461434/lubuntu-how-to-execute-2-commands-in-desktop-file), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223691/how-do-i-create-a-script-file-for-terminal-commands),[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543046/how-can-i-run-an-shell-script-with-desktop-config-file).
Thank you in advance.

### Edit

I tried this new sequence because I realized I have to restart the terminal but it doesn't work as fine as I thought. I activates a the base conda environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
        cd ~/mho;conda init bash;exec bash
        conda activate;conda activate DataBaseOperations;jupyter notebook
}
```

Is there a way to run these last command line in that new terminal?

Comment: What error do you get when you run it from terminal? Do you get the same error if you use the command `./mho.sh` instead of `sh mho.sh`? Try the **Exec** line without the `sh` in the beginning.

Comment: @user68186 Sorry I was just busy but I get the conda init <shell environment>

Comment: @user68186 The command does not seem work this one ``` ./mho.sh```

Comment: I am out of ideas. I hope someone else can help you.

Comment: @user68186 I don't think it would work out because you would have to restart the shell to open conda environment base.